# Make changes with Ubuntu kernel

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to modify `sched.h` to add in some scheduling algorithm. I use `find / -name sched.h` command finding a lot of results.But which one should I really modify ?
[image]

And in `/usr/src`,there are a lot of relating folders whose names are similiar. I'm using ubuntu14.04. Where are my real source code?
[image]

Comment: Off-topic, try http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `uname -a` to see which kernel you are currently running. After that, i would edit the /include/linux/sched.h for that kernel.